# Kriging not working in R studio: method not applicable st_crs

Tags: r, spatial, kriging

I have been working on an exercise using Rstudio. I want to do a kriging interpolation, but I get an error that I have not been able to solve.

I'd appreciate if some of you could tell me how to fix it.

Here my code:

```
#importing libraries

library(raster)
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(gstat)
library(tmap)
library(tidyverse)

#reading csv data

id <- "1u18s9g15USnzNhj-t2EEFYHsW6GZEIgd" # google file ID
read.csv(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", id))

silver_data = read.csv(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", id))

#creating spatial dataframe

silver_2 <- st_as_sf(silver_data, coords = c("long", "lat"))

st_crs(silver_2) <- 4326

#coordinates transformation

silver_utm2 <- st_transform(silver_2, crs=9155)

#setting variogram

ve <- variogram(silver ~ 1, silver_utm2, cutoff = 5000,width = 200) 
plot(ve, plot.numbers = T, asp=1)

#  experimental variogram
vt <- vgm(psill = 350, model = "Sph", range = 2000,nugget = 0) 
plot(ve, pl = T, model = vt)

#automatic adjustment

va <- fit.variogram(ve, vt) 
plot(ve, pl = T, model = va)

#empty raster in order to create grid for kriging interpolation

z <- raster(as(silver_utm2, "Spatial"), ncols = 200, nrows = 80)

# using raster to create grid

grilla2 <- rasterToPoints(z, spatial = TRUE)
gridded(grilla2) <- TRUE
grilla2 <- as(grilla2, "SpatialPixels")

# using kriging function


ok <- krige(silver~1, locations=silver_utm2, newdata=grilla2, model=va)
```

The error that appears:

```
> ok <- krige(silver~1, locations=silver_utm2, newdata=grilla2, model=va)
Error in UseMethod("st_crs<-") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_crs<-' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPixels', 'SpatialPoints', 'Spatial', 'SpatialVector')
```

The tutorial I'm following is https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/416462_1463d00750c54fce89955a925eaa4957.html, but the data are not the same.

Comment: You might have more luck on the [GIS stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) with this question.

Answer (score 0):

`st_crs()` is a function from the package `sf` and is designed to operate on `sf` objects only. As your code stands, `grilla2` is an `sp` object. Convert it to `sf` before using `krige()`.

```
grilla2 <- sf::st_as_sf(grilla2)
```

Comment: Thank you, R is not into my skills and your answer was very usefull

Comment: Hi @Edmundo, were you able to solve your problem?